# Basic server control

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking at server controls for the first time, and I've a question about this code:

```csharp
[Bindable(true)]
[Category("Appearance")]
[DefaultValue("")]
[Localizable(true)]
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
        return ((s == null) ? "[" + this.ID + "]" : s);
    }

    set
    {
        ViewState["Text"] = value;
    }
}
```

I do not understand why this control returns the [id] or the text that is set. I do not see how this makes any sense. Is this just for demonstration or is there a reason for returning the id?

Thanks

Comment: If ViewState["Text"] == null then the first line in the get will throw an exception. You can't cast null to string.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like an example that will show the controls ID if the controls `.Text` property has not been set.

This is a bit of a "debug" procedure to show that the control is actually rendering even though it hasn't got any data set in it's Text property.

Answer (score 0):

Makes no sense to me.  If I'm asking for text, then I expect if there is no text to get either an empty string or null.

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing been set for the Text property, in ViewState with other words, then `this.ID` gets returned.

There's not really a meaning for it but it'll show some text in the Property pane of Visual Studio and on the designer.